# How to check for one JSON object being present in another

Tags: javascript, html, json

I have two sets of data in a **JSON** (data.json) as below :

```
UP = [{"password": "jhonjhon", "username":"jhon"}, {"password": "juliejulie", "username":"julie"}, {"password": "blakeblake", "username":"blake"}];
```

And

```
Admins = '[{"Admin":"jhon"}, {"Admin":"julie"}]';
```

I have an **HTML** form which the user will use to login.

```
<html>
<body>

    <form name="myForm" onsubmit="finalCheck()">
        UserName<input type="text" id="uid" value="UserId"/>
        UserPassword<input type="password" id="pwd" value="UserPwd"/>
        <input type="submit"/>
    </form>
</body>
    <script src="data.json"></script>
    <script src="checking.js"></script>
</html>
```

On the click of the submit button I want to first check if the username (stored in a var, say `x`) entered belongs to the `Admins` list in my **JSON** file or not. Eg: if `x` is `jhon` I want to know if the same `jhon` exists in the `Admins` of the **JSON**.

**JavaScript** as of now is  as :

```
function finalcheck(){
    var x = document.forms["myForm"]["uid"].value;
    var y = document.forms["myForm"]["pwd"].value;
}
```

Help with JavaScript is much appreciated!

Comment: **SECURITY** Never put passwords in user accessible location, always use back-end validation, always encode your passwords. Your approach is VERY VERY insecure. I always can check JSON source file and see what logins I can put to login as admin.

Comment: @justinas yes I will be using a backend validation for the password, but just to make sure I have a clear understanding of JSON, I am trying this example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your should loop through the JSON object and check the `uid` is present or not.

`adminFlag` will set to true if the `x` is present in `Admins`.

Try the code given below:

```
function finalCheck(){
    var adminJSON = JSON.parse(Admins), // since Admins is string, parse to Json first
        length = adminJSON.length,
        x = document.forms["myForm"]["uid"].value,
        y = document.forms["myForm"]["pwd"].value,
        adminFlag = false;

        // for loop to find admin is present or not
        for(var i = 0; i < length; i++){
            if(adminJSON[i].Admin == x){
               adminFlag = true;
               break;
            }
        }
}
```

Comment: if(adminJSON[i] == x){

should be 

 if(adminJSON[i].Admin== x){

Comment: This works perfectly fine! Thanks a lot for your help! Cheers! :)@Utkarsh

Comment: Yes, what Danton says is correct. Although I got the same output even when I simply just tried what Utkarsh suggested. And reason why this would be happening? @Danton

Comment: Shouldn't be working fine I guess. Could you please create a jsfiddle and share the link

Comment: okay no, I just crosschecked and what Utkarsh had initially written does not work. Your suggestion was correct @Danton 
Thanks for the help though, Utkarsh! Cheers! :)

Answer (score 2):

To check if `password` is same as in JSON by user, you have to loop that JSON array and check values:

```
for (var i = 0; i < UP.length; i++) {
   if (UP[i].username == x && UP[i].password == y) {
      for (var j = 0; j < Admins.length; j++) {
          if (Admin[i].Admin == x) {
             //It's correct logins, do something
          }
      }
   }
}
```

---

**SECURITY**

---

***Never*** put passwords in user accessible location, always use back-end validation, always encode your passwords. Your approach is VERY VERY insecure. I always can check JSON source file and see what logins I can put to login as admin

Answer (score 1):

I suppose that this task is for a learning purpose. Please never do this in production. You could play with this sample code. There are a lot of smarter solutions but in my opinion this would help you to understand the basics.

```
var UP = [{"password": "jhonjhon", "username":"jhon"}, {"password": "juliejulie", "username":"julie"}, {"password": "blakeblake", "username":"blake"}];
var ADMINS = [{"Admin":"jhon"}, {"Admin":"julie"}];

function finalcheck()
{
 var x = 'jhon';
 var y = 'jhonjhon';

 for(var i = 0; i < UP.length; i++)
 {
   if (UP[i].password == x && UP[i].username == y)
   {
     console.log(y + ' has access!');
     for (var j = 0; j < ADMINS.length; j++) {
       if (ADMINS[j].Admin == y)
       {
         console.log(y + ' is Admin');
       }
     }
   } 
 }
}
```