# How to read JSON data and compare it with a variable

Tags: javascript, html, json

I have two sets of data in a **JSON** file as :

```
Admins = [{"Admin":"jhonmorris"},{"Admin":"clarkechris"}]
UIDS = [{"password":"Jhon", "username":"jhonmorris"}, {"password":"Jean", "username":"jeanheadly"}, {"password":"Clarke", "username":"clarkechris"}]
```

I have an **HTML** with a user LogIn Page as :

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="data.json" ></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="checking.js" ></script>
</head>
<body>

<form name="myForm" method="post">
UserName<input type="text" id="uid" value="uid"/>
UserPassword<input type="password" id="pwd" value="pwd"/>
<input type="submit" value="Submit" onclick="fnCheck()"/>
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

I have two types of users, one is an `admin` (`Admins`in **JSON**) and the other is a `regular user` (any other user username apart from `Admins` in the **JSON**). When the submit button is clicked, I want to take the userID entered in a var `x` and check if it has the correct password corresponding to it from the `UIDS` in the **JSON**. Further I want to check if the same username belongs to the `Admins` set of data in the **JSON**. If yes, I want to redirect him to google. If not, I want to redirect him to yahoo. 
I am reading the **JSON** data using **JavaScript** as follows :

```
function fnCheck(){
    alert("in fnCheck()");
    if(checkUP() == true){
        alert("checkUP returned true! UserID and Password are correct");
        if(checkAdmin() == true){
            alert("checkAdmin() returned true! going to admin page now");
            window.location = 'http://www.google.com';
        }
        else if(checkAdmin() == false){
            alert("checkAdmin() returned false! going to userIndex page now");
            window.location = 'http://www.yahoo.com';
        }
    }
    else{
        alert("checkUP() returned false. Creds are Invalid!");
    }
}

function checkAdmin(){
    alert("in checkAdmin()");
    //var adminJSON = JSON.parse(Admins); 
    //length = adminJSON.length;
    x = document.forms["myForm"]["uid"].value;

    for(var key in Admins){
        var admin = Admins[key]
        //alert(""+admin.Admin)

        if(admin.Admin == x){
            alert("Admin match found. Returning true!");
            return true;
        }

        else{
            alert("Admin match not found. Returning false");
            return false;
        }
    }
}

function checkUP(){
    alert("hello!!");
    var x = document.forms["myForm"]["uid"].value;
    var y = document.forms["myForm"]["pwd"].value;
    alert("In checkUP, value of x = "+x+" calue of y = "+y);

    for(var key in UP){
        var user = UP[key]

        //if(user.username == x && user.password == y){
        if(x.match(user.username) && x.match(user.password)){
            alert("user.username = "+user.username+"user.password = "+user.password+" User Id and password matched. Returning true now");
            //alert("Matching "+x+ "with "+user.username"+ and "+y+" with user.password"+ y);
            //break;
            return true;
        }

        else{
            //alert("User ID and password did not match. Returning false now. user.username = "+user.username+" user.password = "+user.password);
            //break;
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Ive tried putting alerts to find out what is going wrong at all places, but I still cant figure out what is going wrong. Help is much appreciated!

Comment: It seems like your form is getting submitted. Try adding a `return false;` to the form `onsubmit` and it should work.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31669284/how-to-check-for-one-json-object-being-present-in-another/31669530#31669530

Comment: I tried replacing my the `checkUP` function with what you said on that post. But it doesn't seem to be working. could you create a jstfiddle code for the same and share the link? @Justinas

Comment: Put the JSON in a Structure ---> _var obj = $.parseJSON(Admins);_
Access the Structure value ---> _obj.admin;_
to access an array ---> _obj.admin[i]_
try ----> _alert(obj.admin[1])_ to see what's inside.

Comment: Just thought I'd point out the obvious... Passwords should never be stored in plain text and should most certainly *never* verified in the browser...

Comment: You don't have any JSON there. The file you have with a `.json` file extension contains JavaScript, not JSON.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your function is not called here, don't use `onclick` event of the submit button, better use the `onsubmit` event of the form `onsubmit="fnCheck()"`:

```
<form name="myForm" method="post" onsubmit="fnCheck(event)">
```

**Note:**

- Storing passwords in JSON is a very bad practice which makes your page very weak and unsecure.
- The given file doesn't provide a valid JSON structure, these are only JavaScript objects, assuming that you have a valid JSON, use `JSON.parse(json)` to parse your json objects/arrays.
- There are some errors in your functions such as using `undefined` variables, for example the case of `UP`.
- This is a DEMO where you can test that your function is correctly called with `onsubmit` but you still need to remove/correct the `undefined` variables.

```js
var Admins = [{
  "Admin": "jhonmorris"
}, {
  "Admin": "clarkechris"
}];
UIDS = [{
  "password": "Jhon",
  "username": "jhonmorris"
}, {
  "password": "Jean",
  "username": "jeanheadly"
}, {
  "password": "Clarke",
  "username": "clarkechris"
}];


function fnCheck(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  console.log("in fnCheck()");
  if (checkUP() == true) {
    console.log("checkUP returned true! UserID and Password are correct");
    if (checkAdmin() == true) {
      alert("checkAdmin() returned true! going to admin page now");
      window.location = 'http://www.google.com';
    } else if (checkAdmin() == false) {
      alert("checkAdmin() returned false! going to userIndex page now");
      window.location = 'http://www.yahoo.com';
    }
  } else {
    alert("checkUP() returned false. Creds are Invalid!");
  }
}

function checkAdmin() {
  alert("in checkAdmin()");
  //var adminJSON = JSON.parse(Admins); 
  //length = adminJSON.length;
  x = document.forms["myForm"]["uid"].value;

  for (var key in Admins) {
    var admin = Admins[key]
      //alert(""+admin.Admin)

    if (admin.Admin == x) {
      console.log("Admin match found. Returning true!");
      return true;
    } else {
      console.log("Admin match not found. Returning false");
      return false;
    }
  }
}

function checkUP() {
  console.log("hello!!");
  var x = document.forms["myForm"]["uid"].value;
  var y = document.forms["myForm"]["pwd"].value;
  console.log("In checkUP, value of x = " + x + " calue of y = " + y);

  for (var key in UP) {
    var user = UP[key]

    //if(user.username == x && user.password == y){
    if (x.match(user.username) && x.match(user.password)) {
      console.log("user.username = " + user.username + "user.password = " + user.password + " User Id and password matched. Returning true now");
      return true;
    } else {

      return false;
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<form name="myForm" method="post"  onsubmit="fnCheck(event)">
  UserName
  <input type="text" id="uid" value="uid" />UserPassword
  <input type="password" id="pwd" value="pwd" />
  <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

**EDIT:**

In your function you are returning true/false in the if-statement so it will always leave the function in the first iteration.

You should use a boolean flag and change its value accordingly in the if-statement and return it only in the end of the function:

```
function checkUP() {
  console.log("hello!!");
  var bool = false;
  var x = document.forms["myForm"]["uid"].value;
  var y = document.forms["myForm"]["pwd"].value;
  console.log("In checkUP, value of x = " + x + " calue of y = " + y);

  for (var key in UP) {
    var user = UP[key]
    if (x === user.username && y === user.password) {
      console.log("user.username = " + user.username + "user.password = " + user.password + " User Id and password matched. Returning true now");
      return true;
    }
  }
  return bool;
}
```

Comment: the solution that you poseted is working, but the things is that it is working for only the first set of data in the UP list. It doesn't work on any of the UserIDs that come after. Any suggestions on why this might be happening? @chsdk

Comment: Because you are returning `true` or `false` in the if statement, so it will leave the function, take a look at my EDIT.

Comment: Tried what you said. Now it alerts all the UserIDs and Passwords and after the last one it says that the creds are invalid. I tried putting a break statement after setting the value of bool as true or false but its still not working. @chsdk

Comment: @TheLuminor Great glad it helps.